# CSS Hovering one element and affect the other only where child is

Tags: html, css, react-redux, styled-components

I've seen several questions about hovering on an element and affecting others, but I think my question is a bit more specific.

Let's say I have a card above a white background and the white background is above an image. If I hover the card, I'd like to have it transparent and also the white background, but this last one only where the card is, and not all of it. This way, I'd only see the part of the image that's behind the card.

Is that even possible?

```
const Entrance = styled.div`
   height: 15rem;
   width: 15rem;
   
   background-color: rgb(218, 49, 24);
   overflow: hidden;

   border-radius: 7%;
   margin-left: 2.8rem;
   margin-right: 2.8rem;
   margin-bottom: 4rem;

   a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit
   };
   a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
   };
   &:hover {
      background-color: rgb(255, 247, 214, 0.7);
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
   };
   a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
   };
`;
```

There are going to be several of these entrances/cards. The idea would be to place this over a white div, which while hover would be totally invisible but only in the place where the hovered entrance is.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, please review [ask] provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Comment: Thank you. I had a hard time to figure out what would be necessary to show but since I don't have much of an idea of how to do this, I thought that just showing a card or a white background would be unnecessary. Now I've updated with what I've got so far.
If you could help me, I'd be very glad.

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't quite understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish. But would this be helpful? https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm trying to do. But it probably helps me to explain myself better.
In the example you gave me, you hover the parent and the child changes its style. What I want to do is more or less the opposite. I want the child to change the style of both itself, becoming transparent and I want the part of the parent that's behind the child to become transparent, too.

For example:
layer 0: -
layer 1: +
layer 2: o

Without hovering:
---++oo+++oo+++oo++---

Hovering the left child:
---++--+++oo+++oo++---